# Binary Image Extension?

Tags: c#, .net, image, binary

When we convert an image to binary data, (let's say a .png image) is there a way to get the extension back while converting the binary to image again in .net?

Comment: Do you want to check the file format any then give it a fitting extension, or do you want to restore the original extension? The first is possible for most image formats, since they start with magic-bytes, indicating the format. But it won't tell you if a file originally had a `.jpg` or `.jpeg` extension, or if it was a jpeg file with an entirely different extension.

Comment: i want to restore the original extension?

Comment: What prevents you from storing the filename alongside the image data? Where is the file being stored?

Comment: If you want to restore the original extension, you need to store it obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, no. You can't get the name either. The file name is not generally stored in image data.

If you know what the image format is you can use either a sensible, generally recognised extension or a file extension registered to that file type on your system. Hopefully, these will not differ.

If you don't know the format perhaps you could read it before serialising to binary and prefix it to the representation.

For a less general answer please expand your question.

**EDIT**

I guess you could attempt to display the image using a set of potential formats, then  visually assess all succesful decodes to choose the correct format. Somehow, it seems easier to just include the original extension in the binary serialization.